# svn merge not getting all changes

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I have two branches, dev_branch and trunk

At trunk revision 3656 I created dev_branch

development happens on both branches, then at

```
[trunk: 3770]
[dev_branch: 3777]
```

I merged `[dev_branch 3656-3777]` to `trunk`

development on dev_branch is halted, bug fixing and polish continue on trunk
trunk 3826 is a successful release

Now I want to update dev_branch to resume development, so I use Tortoise SVN to merge
[trunk 3778-3826] to dev_branch.

During the merge, several conflicts arise, and on each I select "use repository"

Here is the problem:  After the merge, there are still many differences between my trunk and dev_branch checkouts.  For example, a change to a css file at revision [Trunk 3790] has not made it to my post-merge dev_branch working copy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just create a new branch for development instead of merging to old branch?

Comment: @Nishant I suppose I could, but then the repository would start filling up with branches and it would be hard to keep track of things

Comment: well, yeah, logically you will have many branches. Buch it would not fill up your hard disk as branches are _cheap copies_ see here http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.using.html

Answer (score -1):

I have 2 recommendations regarding your scenario.

1.) Don't do that 'use repository' thing on conflicts that lightly. Try to resolve conflicts manually whenever it is possible. Especially in your scenario, if you really stopped working on the dev_branch, I don't see, why there can be any conflicts at all. Eventually the change you are missing has been accidentally committed to the dev_branch. Manually resolving the conflict would have brought that to light.

2.) In your scenario I'd rather not merge the things back to the dev_branch. I'd rather create a new dev_branch_2 from trunk.

Regards